# Reading complex binary file formats

Tags: c, file-structure

Is there any book or tutorial that can learn me how to read binary files with a complex structure. I did a lot of attempts to make a program that has to read a complex file format and save it in a struct. But it always failed because of heap overruns etc. that made the program crash.

Answer (score 3):

Probably your best bet is to look for information on binary network protocols rather than file formats. The main issues (byte order, structure packing, serializing and unserializing pointers, ...) are the same but networking people tend to be more aware of the issues and more explicit in how they are handled. Reading and writing a blob of binary to or from a wire really isn't much different than dealing with binary blobs on disk.

You could also find a lot of existing examples in open source graphics packages (such as [netpbm](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/) or [The Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/)). An open source office package (such as [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/)) would also give you lots of example code that deals with complex and convoluted binary formats.

There might even be something of use for you in [Google's Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) or old-school ONC RPC and XDR.

I don't know any books or manuals on such things but maybe a bunch of real life working examples will be more useful to you than a HOWTO guide.

Comment: I seriously want to avoid library's and frameworks (I don't care how they call it). I want to go with standard C functions, and I'm looking for a good tutorial which explains me how to avoid crashes in the program when reading files (all the things that you have to do with memory allocation, garbage collection etc.).

Comment: @Midas: I'm pointing you at examples of things that do similar tasks. There's nothing special about avoiding crashes when reading files, avoiding crashes is a general memory management task. The closest thing to special is "don't `fread` straight into a structure, unpack it byte by byte by hand" and examples will show you how to do that properly.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best tools to debug memory access problems is valgrind.  I'd give that a try next time.  As for books, you'd need to be more specific about what formats you want to parse.  There are lots of formats and many of them are radically different from each other.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Flavor](http://flavor.sourceforge.net/). It allows you to specify the format using C-like structure and will auto-generate the parser for the data in C++ or Java.